# Thickbox not displaying just the image, instead showing full page in lightbox

Tags: images, jquery, gallery, thickbox

I have implemented Thickbox into my wordpress theme. I have a regular Wordpress gallery that now has the lightbox when you click on any of the images. When clicked the lightbox shows up. However, instead of just the image showing up it populates the box with the correct image but displays it on one of my blank custom page templates. My code and screenshots are below for this but I have no clue what is causing this. How do I just get the image in the lightbox?

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_thickbox' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 't5_thickbox_jquery' );
function t5_thickbox_jquery()
{
?>
<script>
jQuery( 'a img.size-medium, a img.attachment-thumbnail' )
    .parent()
    .addClass( 'thickbox' )
    .attr( 'rel', 'page' );
</script>
<?php
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you link to media file when you created the gallery? it looks like you've linked to the attachment page.

Comment: @Milo It worked!!! Sorry it was so simple.

Comment: Please add it as an answer and accept it.